# Quartz: Does not implement interface member

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am using Quartz and using sample code and get the error:

> CS0738 'EmailJob' does not implement interface member
>   `IJob.Execute(IJobExecutionContext)`. `EmailJob.Execute(IJobExecutionContext)` cannot implement `IJob.Execute(IJobExecutionContext)` because it does not > have the matching return type of `Task`.

This is my first go at Quartz so any help would be kindly appreciated.

```
public class EmailJob : IJob  // <<<--- Error on this line
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        using (var message = new MailMessage("user@gmail.com", "user@live.co.uk"))
        {
            message.Subject = "Test";
            message.Body = "Test at " + DateTime.Now;
            using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
            {
                EnableSsl = true,
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user@gmail.com", "password")
            })
            {
                client.Send(message);
            }
        }
    }

 public class JobScheduler
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            IScheduler scheduler = (IScheduler)StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
            scheduler.Start();

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<EmailJob>().Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
                  (s =>
                     s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
                    .OnEveryDay()
                    .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(0, 0))
                  )
                .Build();

            scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
    }
```

I got the code directly from this wonderful article:  http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested your code and it compiles without any changes on my side. Your problem is maybe a wrong namespace import. You can try with the full namespace like this:

```
public class EmailJob : Quartz.IJob
{
    public void Execute(Quartz.IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        using (var message = new MailMessage("user@gmail.com", "user@live.co.uk"))
        {
            message.Subject = "Test";
            message.Body = "Test at " + DateTime.Now;
            using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
            {
                EnableSsl = true,
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user@gmail.com", "password")
            })
            {
                client.Send(message);
            }
        }
    }

   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am still getting the error.  What are your usings and what version of Quartz are you using?

Comment: I switched to 2.4.1 and used your code and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

It looks to me like you're using the 3.0 version (double check which package you grabbed from Nuget).  The IJob interface has changed. The Execute method now returns a Task instead of being a void method (which explains why you're seeing the issue you're seeing).

`Task Execute(
    IJobExecutionContext context
)`

[Here are the 3.0 docs](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/3.0/html/).

As noted by Bidou, version 3 is still in alpha. You need to uninstall this version and replace it with a previous version, or adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: Note that version 3.0 is still in Alpha 2 !

Comment: @Bidou True, I'll note that in my answer. OP should probably uninstall that version and install a previous version consistent with the tutorial referenced.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.

Fixed it by running `Install-Package Quartz -Version 3.0.0-alpha1 -Pre` in the Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 1):

Run this line in your Package Manager to install the appropriate package:
Install-Package Quartz -Version 2.2.4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).